# What to look: R Square or Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) for a multiple linear regression model?

Tags: model, r-squared

I made a multiple linear regression model. This model uses 3 predictors to determine the response (Temperature in K). This model gives a R square of 0.234 (Indicates that this model is a failure). But when i calculated RMSE to be 0.935 K which is very good.

My model gives very good RMSE but very bad R square. So my question is, what conclusions can be made for this model in terms of its accuracy?

Comment: Why do you believe your $R^2$ is good and your RMSE is bad? [Is my model any good, based on the diagnostic metric (R2
/ AUC / accuracy / etc) value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/414349/1352)