# RMSE with and without standardizing the output variable

Tags: time-series, error, standardization, rms, feature-scaling

I have a time series data that I would like to be able to forecast. I was trying to standardize the data as my columns are all of different ranges. I have standardized the input variables, but was reluctant of whether should I standardize the output variable or not. The following code snippet describeswhat I did.

```
class OutOfSampleForecasting:

    def __init__(self, train_df, test_df):
        train_df = train_df.dropna()
        test_df = test_df.dropna()

        #make the 'date' the index column 
        train_df = train_df.set_index('date')
        test_df = test_df.set_index('date')

        #change rows were demand = 0, make them demand = 1
        train_df.loc[train_df.demand == 0, 'demand'] = 1
        test_df.loc[test_df.demand == 0, 'demand'] = 1

        self.X_train = np.array(train_df.loc[:, train_df.columns != 'demand'])
        self.y_train = np.array(train_df.loc[:, 'demand'])

        self.X_test = np.array(test_df.loc[:, test_df.columns != 'demand'])
        self.y_test = np.array(test_df.loc[:, 'demand'])

        #standardizing only the training, applying parameters to testing 
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        self.X_train = scaler.fit_transform(self.X_train)
        self.X_test = scaler.transform(self.X_test)

        y_scaler = StandardScaler()
        self.y_train = y_scaler.fit_transform(self.y_train.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
        self.y_test = y_scaler.transform(self.y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)

        print('avg demand: %.3f', np.mean(self.y_test))

    def forecast(self, model, model_name, isCatBoost=False):
        print('*** Results for %s ***' % model_name)
        t1 = time.time()
        if isCatBoost:
            model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train, verbose=False)
        else:
            model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
        y_pred = model.predict(self.X_test)
        t2 = time.time()
        time_taken = float(t2 - t1) / 60
        print('time taken %.3f min' % time_taken)
        self.print_stats(self.y_test, y_pred)

    def print_stats(self, y_test, y_pred):
        r2_Score = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
        rmse_score = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
        mse_score = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
        mae_score = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
        print('R^2: %.3f\nRMSE: %.3f\nMSE: %.3f\nMAE: %.3f\n' % (r2_Score, rmse_score, mse_score, mae_score))

        plt.plot(y_test, label='actual')
        plt.plot(y_pred, label='predicted')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()

    def run_all(self):
        self.forecast(Ridge(), 'Ridge Regression')
        self.forecast(Lasso(), 'Lasso Regression')
        self.forecast(ElasticNet(), 'Elastic Net Regression')
        self.forecast(DecisionTreeRegressor(), 'Decision Tree')
        self.forecast(RandomForestRegressor(), 'Random Forest')
        self.forecast(AdaBoostRegressor(), 'Ada Boost')
        self.forecast(GradientBoostingRegressor(), 'Gradient Descent')
        self.forecast(XGBRegressor(), 'XGBoost')
        self.forecast(CatBoostRegressor(), 'Cat Boost', True)
        self.forecast(SVR(), 'Support Vector Regressor')
```

As you can see in this part, I am stnadardizing both the input and the output variable:

```
#standardizing only the training, applying parameters to testing 
            scaler = StandardScaler()
            self.X_train = scaler.fit_transform(self.X_train)
            self.X_test = scaler.transform(self.X_test)

            y_scaler = StandardScaler()
            self.y_train = y_scaler.fit_transform(self.y_train.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
            self.y_test = y_scaler.transform(self.y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
```

However, what made me wonder is the RMSE results (and other metrics) with and without standardizing the output variable:

**With standardizing output variable:**

```
RMSE: 1.213
MSE: 1.472
MAE: 1.014
```

**Without Standardizating output variable**

```
RMSE: 48.784
MSE: 2379.876
MAE: 42.317
```

So basically, which results should I consider ?

I assume that what happened when standardizing the output variable is that ALL COLUMNS are now of the same scale, but is and RMSE of 1.2 good ? Or is an somehow a 'transformed' RMSE ? And what should I do in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There's no useful meaning I can see in a RMSE/MSE/MAE calculated based on standardized data. Standardization has changed the variable and removed the  interpretability of RMSE/MAE/MSE.

2) As for what RMSE value is good, this is impossible for us to say for reasons I explain in this thread [Is my model any good, based on the diagnostic metric ($R^2$/ AUC/ accuracy/ RMSE etc.) value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/414349/121522)

3) It's not obvious that standardization is necessary (or even useful) in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much. this makes sense. Can you please answer my question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427227/outer-folds-errors-in-nested-cross-validation I would really appreciate this !!

Comment: @Hiyam You're welcome! Wish I could help, but I don't know enough to answer the new question adequately. FWIW, I think if you search for 'rolling forecast' on this site you may find some relevant questions.

Comment: @Hiyam Rob Hyndman has also written about this on his blog e.g. https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/rolling-forecasts/