# How to choose the balance between model fit vs AUC (diagnostic accuracy)?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, goodness-of-fit, auc, calibration

I would like to know how we can choose between model fit (calibration) vs AUC when building the predictive model. For example, if I have one predictor which improves the model fit but results in a lower AUC (e.g. 0.80 -> 0.70), would you still include this predictor in this predictive model?

Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: By what measure does the model fit improve?

Comment: @Dave I am thinking of using the likelihood ratio test to compare models

Comment: Likelihood ratio testing considers the performance of the log loss, which is a strictly proper scoring rule. AUC is not strictly proper, so there is a sense in which log loss is preferred to AUC. Frank Harrell, for instance, considers log loss the gold standard for model performance.

Comment: Thank you! When it comes to model fit, between AIC vs likelihood ratio testing, which one is better?

Comment: Do you mean AIC or AUC?

Comment: AIC (Akaike information criterion)!

Comment: @Dave Just want to follow up with one question: if I include one predictor in my model, it improves the model fit (ie., the p-value between the nested model and my new model by likelihood ratio testing is <0.05) but the p-value of this predictor itself is >0.05, should I still include this predictor in my model?

Comment: Variable selection is its own topic that warrants its own question (or textbook...or master's degree in statistics). Briefly, what you're doing is some kind of stepwise regression, [which is problematic](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/). You seem to be working with collinear features, too, which makes stepwise regression even more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the trouble here is that $AUC$ and the likelihood ratio test are based on different ideas.

The $AUC$ measures the extent to which the predictions are separated by true category: the ability of the model to discriminate or discern between categories. Notably, if you divide the predictions by two or apply any other monotonically increasing function (multiplying by $1/2$ is an increasing function), you do not change the order of the predictions, so you do not change the extent to which the predictions are separable into the two categories. Consequently, $AUC$ does not consider the output calibration and if a predicted probability of $p$ corresponds to the event truly happening with probability $p$.

The likelihood involves both the ability of the model to discriminate but also the calibration of the outputs. Consequently, if adding a variable slightly lowers the ability to discriminate but dramatically improves the calibration, the likelihood favors adding this variable. However, the $AUC$ will suffer when you add this variable.

If you want to consider the fit according to the likelihood and also want to have some kind of "absolute" measure of performance ([it is hard to say that any particular score counts as "good"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414349/is-my-model-any-good-based-on-the-diagnostic-metric-r2-%7B0b5f1393-24cf-4cbe-8b00-592bcf116029%7D-accuracy-rmse/414350#414350), but it can be nice to give some context for a likelihood value that lacks an easy interpretation like mean absolute error), you might consider McFadden's $R^2$, which compares the likelihood of your model (fraction numerator) to the likelihood of a reasonable baseline model that always predicts the overall probability (fraction denominator).

$$
R^2_{McFadden} = 1-\left(
\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left[
y_i\log(\hat y_i) + (1 - y_i)\log(1 - \hat y_i)
\right]
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left[
y_i\log(\bar y) + (1 - y_i)\log(1 - \bar y)
\right]
}
\right)
$$

In the equation above, $y_i\in\left\{0, 1\right\}$ are the true labels, $\hat y_i$ are the predicted probabilities, and $\bar y$ is the overall probability of the event coded as $1$.

While McFadden's $R^2$ does not seem to be as popular in machine learning circles as the $AUC$, it is part of the literature, and a big part of me thinks that it should be a more popular metric.