# Should I use cross validation for simple linear regression model?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, model-selection

I have a data set with 181 observations. I have 9 predictors and I have developed different regression models using ordinary linear regression and stepwise linear regression. Now I'm trying to decide which model to choose. Here's summary of the models that I want to choose from:
[image]

RMSE% is RMSE divided by mean of actual data expressed as a percentage. and any column labeled CV means that I used 80% of my data to train the model and 20% to test and the last three columns with CV is obtained using the testing set. Those columns without CV uses all the data.

So I have two questions here:

1. based on the fact that I am using linear regression and have only 181 observations, should I use training and testing set or should I just use R2 and RMSE?
2. according to R2 and RMSE, model 2 is better. But is it a good model as the RMSE% is 14? isn't it too high? does it mean that I'm overfitting?

Comment: Stepwise regression generally produces biased results, as is explained well in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection)

Comment: Instead, you could consider using [tag:regularization] methods to develop your model, though it would be helpful if you specified what your goal for the model is.

Comment: [Nobody here can tell you whether the model is good because that needs context to answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414349/is-my-model-any-good-based-on-the-diagnostic-metric-r2-auc-accuracy-rmse)